# Is there a way to specify defaultProps for a variant?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I created variant for MuiButton like so...

```js
    const theme = createTheme({
      components: {
        MuiButton: {
          variants: [{
            props: {
              variant: 'myVariantX'
            },
            style: {
              backgroundColor: 'blue'
            }
          }]
        }
      },
    });
```

...I know I can do this...

```js
    const theme = createTheme({
      components: {
        // Name of the component
        MuiButton: {
          defaultProps: {
            // The props to change the default for.
            disableRipple: true, // No more ripple, on the whole application !
          },
        },
      },
    });
```

... but is there a way I could specify defaultProps for my 'myVariantX' variant? Dont want to target all MuiButtons. Something like...

```js
    const theme = createTheme({
      components: {
        MuiButton: {
          variants: [{
            props: {
              variant: 'myVariantX',
              defaultProps: {
                disableRipple: true
              }
            },
            style: {
              backgroundColor: 'blue'
            }
          }]
        }
      },
    });
```

Comment: Your custom theme should not work because `MuiCardHeader` component does not contain `variant` prop. So, it should be throwing an error with `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'variant' does not exist in type 'Partial<CardHeaderProps<"div", {}, "span", "span">>'`. Do you not getting this error?

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto I am not getting this error, weird

Comment: Yes, very weird. You can check that `MuiCardHeader` does not have `variant` prop [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/card-header/#props).

Comment: Are you using javascript or typescript project? Could be related to that.

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto Typescript. I tried with IconButton too and it works.

Comment: I will update my question with MuiButton only

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto any idea how to handle this now?